# jquery plugin alternatives to jquery ui draggable?

Tags: jquery, css

seems to be a bug in jquery UI when trying to drag a draggable outside the screen (i.e. when the page scrolls down) where the draggable loses it's position relative to the cursor.

you can see the bug here... http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/default.html

are there any other recommended jquery draggable plugins i could use instead?

alernatively i could try and fix the bug but I fear it's beyond me atm!

thanks :)

Comment: Have you reported the bug? Someone from jQuery might know of a fix. http://bugs.jquery.com/report

Comment: i just tried the IRC channel & they said they were rewriting the plug in the next few months anyway, just need a stopgap until then....

Comment: did you try working around with the options such as scroll and containment ( http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/#option-containment ) ?

Comment: yeah - doesn't seem to make much difference...

Comment: I tested with chrome with scroll=false And I don't see any bug.

Comment: BiAiB - there's no bug because the page doesn't scroll! lol

Answer (score 9, accepted):

By far the best drag/drop plugins I've found for jQuery are located here: http://threedubmedia.com/.

They provide new jQuery event handlers for the key stages of a drag-and-drop action, which allow you to customise the behaviour very easily. Just check out the demos to see what can be achieved using them.